# Update the set-bounty page to include the grace period

Tags: feature-request

As it stands, the set-bounty page ([here](https://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties) is SU's for example) makes no mention of the grace period.

I would suggest that the page be edited to have a section saying something like the following:

> To assist forgetful bounty owners, there is a 24 hour grace period at the end of every bounty. During this grace period, the question will not be featured, but the bounty can still be awarded at any time.

Comment: ... and a few days later, we have the first "I took the grace period into account, and then my cat needed surgery. Can we extend the grace period?" question here on meta?

Comment: So you are saying it should be left purposefully incomplete?

Comment: I haven't made up my mind, but you have to admit it's a counter-argument.

Comment: Don't think so. Alternative is having the same problem, but with people asking "what is this grace period?" I don't think either is a real problem.

Comment: +1 IMO we definitely need a grace period, and it needs to be clearly defined.  I'm sure many of us are more busy than we are forgetful, and 24 hours feels like a sensible minimum grace period.